# Write selenium results into a json file

Tags: java, json, selenium, automated-tests

I need to integrate selenium server (java) tests results with PractiTest (test management tool). To do that I need to save my test results into a JSON file. How can I do that?

Comment: What Testing framework you are using? TestNG or JUnit? How do you save your test results now?

Comment: I am using eclipse with junit and currently saving my results into a text file

Answer (score -1):

Use a java test framework that supports json reports, or write your own report formatter for the test framework you're using. Most test frameworks for java support generating the test report in whatever format you want.

Comment: I am using JUnit but when try to import a json library it does not recognize it: import org.junit.?